# Function runs separately for every letter typed javascript (font-weight change)

Tags: javascript, css, function, onchange

I have this variable font that I made and I want to implement it on a website, where when the user types, the font-weight for each letter grows. I have this code right now that it grows for the whole text typed, but everything changes there, not each letter (so what I need the code to do is say for each keydown event the font-weight changes but not the whole text, so the first letter typed would have the smaller font-weight and stay that way but the following letters would grow in font-weight).

```js
document.getElementById("testarea").onkeypress = function () { myFunction() };

var initWeight = 101
;
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("testarea").style.fontWeight = initWeight+=50  ;
}
```

```html
<p id="testarea" contentEditable="true">
   Type your text here
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is happening because you are changing all container, so, you need to have a container for each letter you want to grow.

In myFunction you should indentify the letter should grow and pass into a new container with new class, and add this to a new container:

`document.getElementById("mynewletter").style.fontWeight = initWeight+=50`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't modify the input itself to look better so i used an additional div, but you can use this as a start:

```js
let initWeight = 8;

document.getElementById("testarea").onkeypress = function(event) {
  myFunction(event.key)
};

function myFunction(letter) {
  initWeight += 2;
  const letterHTML = '<span style="font-size:' + initWeight + 'px">' + letter + '</span>'
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += letterHTML
}
```

```css
.myInput {
  border-style: groove;
}
```

```html
<div class="myInput" id="testarea" contentEditable="true"> insert text </div>
<div id="result" contentEditable="true"></div>
```